# Find the geometric locus of vertices A of the triangles ABC with the given base BC and such that $\widehat{B} > \widehat{C}$

Tags: geometry

When I tried it, I figure that the right triangle, with angle A being 90, to satisfy the question. I just don't think is quite correct. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\widehat{B}>\widehat{C}$ if and only if $AC>AB$, hence the locus is one of the two open half-planes cut by the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:***

Draw the base $BC$. Then draw the perpendicular bisector to $BC$. Check what happens on either side of it.